# Почему на IOS не отображается текст

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css3, html5

Всем привет
На айфоне не отображается текст H1 , сайт http://vps26298ru.hyperhost.name/ , хотя на андроиде и на пк (windows) всё отлично

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

в кроссбраузерности не силен но убери эту часть h1, .h1 {
font-display: swap;
} чисто догадка

если не наладица добавь просто h1 без стилей, fonts и тд, если все норм подключи стили, если норм подключи fonts, по схеме проблему найти не трудно

Answer (score 0):

Уберите css между пунктиром и текст пропадать перестанет.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .elementor-widget-trydo-main-demo-banner.center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  
  
  /*--------------------*/
  .slide .inner h1.title {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  /*--------------------*/
  
  
  
  .about-with-experience-area .about-inner.inner {
    padding: 45px 20px 0 20px;
  }
}
```